# What is expected distribution for a Kubernetes pod startup time

Tags: kubernetes

On my test cluster, starting a pod seems to consistently take ~12 seconds, give or take one. I would like to know if that is reasonable, or if I am doing something wrong, either in configuring the pod, or in measuring the time, or configuring the cluster.

According to https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/3952 and https://medium.com/google-cloud/profiling-gke-startup-time-9052d81e0052, I believe what I am getting is excessively slow.

The way I measure startup is by running the following script and counting how many times it prints "Pending", and that is my startup time in seconds. Since due to the sleep command, I get almost exactly one "Pending" per second.

```sh
id=mypod1
tee job.yaml <<EOF
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: clusterrunner-build-${id}
spec:
  containers:
  - name: clusterrunner-slave
    image: jdanekrh/clusterrunner-slave
    command: ["bash", "-c", "echo bof; sleep 5; echo lek"]
  restartPolicy: Never
EOF

kubectl create -f job.yaml
while kubectl get pod/clusterrunner-build-${id} -o jsonpath='{.status.phase}' | grep Pending; do
    sleep 1
done
kubectl logs -f po/clusterrunner-build-${id}
kubectl delete -f job.yaml
```

Comment: I don't think that 12 seconds is very slow, but it is hard to say. What is jdanekrh/clusterrunner-slave? The image needs to be downloaded or at least verified (no tag, so must be checked for changes) and started. How long does it take to simply run the same image with docker?

Comment: I am not staring the pod for the first time on that node, so it does not actually pull anything. With Docker, I get for `$ time docker run --rm -it jdanekrh/clusterrunner-slave true` timing `real    0m1.025s, user    0m0.018s sys     0m0.005s`. I hoped to get something <5s in Kubernetes, preferably ~2s.

Comment: Good point about no-tag meaning `:latest` meaning `imagePullPolicy: Always`. That is certainly slowing it down for me. I will try with a tag set. (source: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#updating-images)

Comment: @user2612030 tag helped a lot, pods now start up in ~4s for me!

Comment: That's good news!